# Как эффективно отфильтровать List<Integer> с помощью Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

Дана задача:

> Метод должен вернуть список, который содержит симметричную разность двух подмножеств целочисленных значений:
>
> - первое подмножество: все чётные значения в списке `integerList`;
> - второе подмножество: значения в списке `integerList` за исключением первых k элементов.
> - Результат должен быть отсортирован по убыванию.
>
> Параметры:
>
> k положительное целое число; integerList список положительных целых чисел.
>
> **Входные данные:**
>
> k = 5
>
> integerList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>
> **Вывод:** [9, 7, 4, 2]

Я получил 2 коллекции:

1. С `even` числами от начальной коллекции.
2. После метода `skip` на основной коллекции.

У меня проблема заключается в том, как сравнить их с основной коллекцией (может `flatMap`) - это основное, что я не могу понять.
И 1 и 2 пункты я делал отдельными шагами, как можно сделать так, чтобы все было только в 1 потоке?

Мое начало..

```java
public static List<Integer> f(int k, List<Integer> integerList) {
    List<Integer> evens = integerList.stream().filter(even -> even % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> skippedList = integerList.stream().skip(k).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<>(evens);
    sum.addAll(skippedList);
    System.out.println(sum);

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно правильно отфильтровать данные, чтобы сразу получить нужный результат, и затем отсортировать полученный список.

Поскольку заданы такие условия для отбора:

1. любые чётные числа
2. числа после индекса `k`
3. числа, отвечающие обоим условиям, должны быть исключены (симметричная разность двух списков)

В результате должны остаться только те данные, для которых *одновременно* удовлетворяется лишь одно из условий, то есть:

1. любые чётные числа *до индекса `k`* ИЛИ
2. *любые нечётные числа* после индекса `k`

Таким образом, достаточно переписать метод следующим образом:

```java
public static List<Integer> f(int k, List<Integer> list) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .filter(i -> i < k && list.get(i) % 2 == 0 || i >= k && list.get(i) % 2 == 1)
            .mapToObj(list::get)
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println(f(5, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)));
```

Результат:

```
[9, 7, 4, 2]
```

Условие фильтра можно ещё упростить, если воспользоваться операцией "исключающего ИЛИ": числа с индексом, меньшим `k` XOR НЕчётные числа, или ещё один эквивалент: числа с индексом НЕ меньшим `k` XOR чётные числа:

```java
public static List<Integer> f(int k, List<Integer> list) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .filter(i -> i < k ^ list.get(i) % 2 != 0)
            //.filter(i -> i >= k ^ list.get(i) % 2 == 0)
            .mapToObj(list::get)
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Для проверки на нечётность следует использовать `x % 2 != 0`, так как для отрицательных чисел остаток от деления на 2 отрицателен и равен -1.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, можно улучшить, но так работает:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static List<Integer> f(int k, List<Integer> integerList) {
        List<Integer> evens = integerList.stream().filter(even -> even % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> skippedList = integerList.stream().skip(k).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Stream.concat(evens.stream().filter(e -> !skippedList.contains(e)),
               skippedList.stream().filter(e -> !evens.contains(e))).
               sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f(5, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)));
    }
}
```

```
[9, 7, 4, 2]
```